# PHP CURL, PayPal Redirect

Tags: php, redirect, curl, paypal

Lemme explain what I want to do:

1. Capture custom info in a form.
2. User Submits Form.
3. I capture the data in a DB.
4. I pass entry ID to PayPal(custom var), and take user to PayPal.
5. User puts in info on PayPal and submits payment.
6. PayPal sends me IPN.
7. I update status of DB entry to paid.

I have all this working except step 4. In the php where i capture the data, I am trying to use curl to POST to the PayPal page... but it doesn't want to redirect as it post the data.

New to CURL, so I am sure I've made a mistake in that area.

This is what I have with $custom just set to a random string instead of DB id:

```
    $url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    //$url = 
    $cmd = "_s-xclick";
    $custom = "id1234";
    $b_id = "";

    switch($_POST["streamer"]){
        case "mrhyubusa":
            $b_id = "BTS5M8QXSGR3G";
            break;              
        default:
            break;
    }   

    //set POST variables
    $fields = array(
                'cmd' => urlencode($cmd),
                'hosted_button_id' => urlencode($b_id),
                'custom' => urlencode($custom)
    );

    //url-ify the data for the POST
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
    rtrim($fields_string, '&'); 

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0):

When using Payments Standard like you are you don't need CURL.  Payments Standard just works with basic HTML forms.  All you need to do is grab the HTML snippet PayPal provides in your button manager and paste it into your page where you want it to show up.

You'll have to add the custom parameter, which does work with hosted buttons as of a couple of months ago when I tested it (it didn't used to work with hosted buttons).

CURL would come into play if you were making calls to the web service API's.  Again, though, with Payments Standard you don't need that.

Comment: I understand I can just do a button that goes straight to the PayPal page. Issue I am having is putting all the info from my form into my DB, then sending them to the page the PayPal button normally would.

 That is why I am trying to do it with curl after the DB insert. Perhaps I am being stupid, but that is the only way I really saw to do it. i didn't want to create a second form just to load it and then submit it. I wanted to do it all on the backend to make the process as seamless as possible fore the user.

Comment: Guess I could submit my form with Ajax, then when it completes submit a second hidden form that is the payPal button instead of using curl ... I'll do that if not better solution exist.

Comment: Or just use IPN to handle all your data inserts.